# How to create switch() via array without if-else?

Tags: php

I have two functions and want to when `$test=one`, `function1()` runs and when `$test=two`, `function2()` runs. Like this:

```
switch ($test)
 {

case "one":
function1();
break;

case "two":
function2();
break;

 }
```

Now how do it (selecting) via array? any body know?

how set key of array on function ? something like this:

```
array("one"=>function1(),"two"=>function2());
```

Comment: Please add an example how you want to use it then!

Comment: I want: when $test=one then echo 'one', and when $test=two then echo 'two'. using array php

Comment: no, echo string of 'test', or run a function.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking for here ?

Comment: I want to run function1 if $test='one'. how do it without using if-else and switch case ?

Comment: @halfer tnx for editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
function func1()
{
    print "111\n";
}

function func2()
{
    print "222\n";
}

//put functions names into an array
$functions = array(
    'one' => "func1",
    'two' => "func2",
);

$test = 'two';

if(isset($functions[$test]))
{
    call_user_func($functions[$test]);
}
```

Output:

```
222
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: your solution is great, but i don't want any `if` and function like `call_user_func();` . anyway tnx for Training `call_user_func();` to me. :)

Comment: can you tell me which one is better ? `call_user_func($functions[$test]);`  OR  `$functions[$test]();`

Comment: @Fatemeh It's actually the same - php has to search for the function with appropriate name in it's functions table. The difference is only in syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of user4035 is correct, but in other word we can use:

```
$arr[$test]();
```

instead

```
call_user_func($arr[$test]);
```

then: (full code) :

```
  function func1(){
    echo 'func1 runing';
        }

  function func2(){
    echo 'func2 runing';
        }

     $test='one';

     $arr=array ('one'=>'func1','two'=>'func2');
     $arr[$test]();
```

output:

```
func1 runing
```